# Betweenness and shortest paths in R

Tags: r

I've been reviewing this interesting article:

http://kieranhealy.org/blog/archives/2013/06/09/using-metadata-to-find-paul-revere/

As an exercise, I've been picking through the various steps taken to convict Mr. Revere of treason.  At one point, the author uses the betweenness function of the **igraph library**, which is described as:

> "The vertex and edge betweenness are (roughly) defined by the number of geodesics (shortest paths) going through a vertex or an edge."

So, in the case of the article, how many shortest communication paths between pairs of people go through each of the 254 people being considered?  I diverted a little from the article, though, and I'm wondering if I'm thinking naively.

A 254 x 254 matrix has 64516 elements.  However, trivial elements (those on the diagonal-- a person talking to herself is obviously the shortest path from X to X) can be discounted, leaving (it seems) 254 * 254 - 254 = 64262 total nontrivial ordered pairings.  But, these are not directional-- that is, the shortest path between a particular pair X and Y is the same, regardless of which of X or Y is the sender and which is the receiver.

So, we can reduce our number of pairings:  `(254 * 254 - 254) / 2 = 32131`.

Since this also happens to be the number of combinations of 2 selected from 254, even better-- a fine coincidence! ;-)

Then, just for fun, I did:

```
((254 * 254 - 254) / 2) - sum(betweenness(person.g)) = 10061
```

What does this number mean?  It almost seems to say that there are 10,061 pairings for whom no path exists, but I don't see how that can be.  Do I misunderstand betweenness?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `It almost seems to say that there are 10,061 pairings for whom no path exists, but I don't see how that can be` Why not? For example, if they made up two subgroups that had no connections between them, that's `(254/2)^2=16129` paths that are impossible.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: the graph is actually connected (`clusters(person.g)`) so there is a connection for each pair.

Comment: Sorry, @DavidRobinson, that's a good question.  I glossed over my reasoning.  In the same igraph library is shortest.paths.  Just running it on the person.g matrix results in the shortest path length for all pairs.  So, I did:

max(shortest.paths(person.g)).

The answer was 3.  Also, just visually inspecting the output of shortest.paths(person.g) showed nothing that suggested the undefined length of "unconnectable" people.  I would expect that to just out quickly if, in fact, about 30% of pairings of those rebellious colonists were unable to communicate via any set of intermediaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check what happens on a simpler graph,
you will notice that shortest paths of length 1 
do not enter the computation.

```
betweenness( graph.lattice( 3 ) )
# [1] 0 1 0
```

Shortest paths of length 2 will be used once (for the point in the middle),
but shortest paths of length 3 or more will be used several times: 
once for each point in the middle.

```
betweenness( graph.lattice( 5 ) )
# [1] 0 3 4 3 0
```

In this example, the shortest paths are

```
length 1: 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5  (not used)
length 2: 1-3, 2-4, 3-5       (each used once, for the betweenness of 2, 3 and 4)
length 3: 1-4, 2-5            (each used twice, for 2,3 and 2,4)
length 4: 1-5                 (each used 3 times, for 2, 3 and 4)
```

In other words, a shortest path of length k is counted k-1 times.

```
p <- shortest.paths(person.g)
sum( p[upper.tri(p)] - 1 )
# [1] 22070
sum( betweenness( person.g ) )
# [1] 22070
```

Comment: Ah, ok... the multiple counting appears supported by:  table(cut(shortest.paths(person.g), breaks = -1:3)).  Accounting for multiply-counted elements, the numbers end up as expected.  Thank you very much for the explanation.  I'd upvote, but I sadly lack the reputation, I am told.